# Put a "(" and ")" on string of sqlquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
string sqlquery=
Select userPropID , PropType, PropLoc, PropTranType,PropFloorNo From dbo.tbl_allProperties 
WHERE PostPropFor = 'Sale' AND  PropCity = '4320-1001041'  
AND PropType ='Business Centre' OR PropType ='Space in Shopping Mall' OR PropType ='Commercial Showroom' AND PropImage !='~/user_prop_images/noImage.jpg'
```

Above sqlquery does not have fix field, it may expand with more fields as user enters value into fields/controls.
My requirement is :

1. if there is a single 'PropType', do nothing.
2. if more than one 'PropType', put a '(' before first 'PropType' and
   a ')' after the value of last 'PropType'.

Above query should be like this:

```
Select userPropID , PropType, PropLoc, PropTranType,PropFloorNo From dbo.tbl_allProperties 
WHERE PostPropFor = 'Sale' AND  PropCity = '4320-1001041'  
AND (PropType ='Business Centre' OR PropType ='Space in Shopping Mall' OR PropType ='Commercial Showroom') AND PropImage !='~/user_prop_images/noImage.jpg'
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and show an example of the output?

Answer (score 2):

Your description modifies the values on separate rows.  If so, you can use `row_number()` and a `case` statement:

```
Select userPropID,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by userPropId order by PropTYpe) = 1 then '(' + PropType
             when row_number() over (partition by userPropId order by PropTYpe desc) = 1 then PropType + ')'
             else PropType
        end) as PropType
       PropLoc, PropTranType, PropFloorNo
From dbo.tbl_allProperties 
where PostPropFor = 'Sale' AND  PropCity = '4320-1001041'  AND 
      PropType in ('Business Centre', 'Space in Shopping Mall', 'Commercial Showroom') AND
      PropImage !='~/user_prop_images/noImage.jpg';
```

Comment: Mr Gordon Linoff, Thanks for your quick response. Your solution gives the same result as of my query. I've solved my problem using CASE statement. Again thanks. Problem has been resolved.